# Stability proof of nominal MPC with terminal cost and constraint

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, stability-theory

While going trough [these slides](https://www.uiam.sk/pc11/data/workshops/mpc/MPC_PC11_Lecture1.pdf), I wasn't able to make sense of the following on slide 32: (if only providing the url to the slides is not ok I will edit the question, but doing it like that saves a lot of time)

Why does the fact that $V_f$ is a Lyapunov function result in
$$V_f(\tilde{x}_{N+1}) − V_f(x_N) + l(x_N, κ_f(x_N))\leq 0?$$

Comment: Can you add a summary, because slide 32 alone does not give any context for the mentioned variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply assumption 3 on slide 29. In practice, this assumption can be ensured via suitable choice/design of the terminal cost and the terminal set.

Comment: you're right - cannot believe I missed that!